# Pandas dataframe.query to SQL 'LIKE' WITHOUT using engine='python'

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pandas

There are plenty of relevant examples of replicating a SQL "LIKE" condition in Pandas dataframe.query(). However, all of the examples I am finding essentially boil down to utilizing a `column.str.contains()`, which requires the additional `engine='python'`.

I am working with very large datasets, frequent queries, and complex WHERE conditions. The performance hit for using the python engine adds up quickly for my use case.

Is there a syntactic equivalent that utilizes the standard (and SUPER FAST) numexpr engine? I know that I can utilize other methods outside of .query(), but with complex queries they can become quite verbose.

Answer (score 2):

Let's set up some sample data first:

```
import pandas as pd
import string
import numexpr as ne

n = 10_000_000
k = 5
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': pd.np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase),size=n*k).view((pd.np.str_,k)),
                   'col2': pd.np.random.random(n)})
```

In order to make `contains` work with the `numexpr` engine you'll have to add `.values`. The query is still slow, however, and the reason is **not** the `.values` operation as you can see from the comparison with and without `.values` for the `python` engine:

```
%timeit df.query("col1.str.contains('a').values", engine='numexpr')
#1 loop, best of 3: 3.48 s per loop

%timeit df.query("col1.str.contains('a')", engine='python')
#1 loop, best of 3: 3.55 s per loop

%timeit df.query("col1.str.contains('a').values", engine='python')
#1 loop, best of 3: 3.52 s per loop
```

The performance benefit of numexpr is negligible however for relatively simple queries (see also https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#performance-of-query). As we can see, `.values` adds just about 60 ms:

```
%timeit df.query("col2.values < .5", engine='numexpr')
1 loop, best of 3: 363 ms per loop

%timeit df.query("col2 < .5", engine='numexpr')
1 loop, best of 3: 298 ms per loop

%timeit df.query("col2 < .5", engine='python')
1 loop, best of 3: 299 ms per loop
```

[`Numexpr` does support `contains`](https://numexpr.readthedocs.io/projects/NumExpr3/en/latest/user_guide.html#supported-functions) but it's not implemented in pandas. An - admittedly not very elegant - workaround is to copy the values from pandas into arrays and then use **`numexpr.evaluate`** for boolean indexing:

```
%timeit df.query("col1.str.contains('a').values & (col2 < .5)", engine='numexpr')
#1 loop, best of 3: 3.53 s per loop

%timeit df.query("col1.str.contains('a') & (col2 < .5)", engine='python')
#1 loop, best of 3: 3.45 s per loop

%%timeit
arr1 = df.col1.to_numpy(bytes)
arr2 = df.col2.to_numpy()
df[ne.evaluate("contains(arr1, 'a') & (arr2 < .5)")]
#1 loop, best of 3: 1.18 s per loop
```

This is about 3 times faster than the pandas version, including the overhead for copying to arrays and boolean indexing. `ne.evaluate("contains(arr1, 'a') & (arr2 < .5)")` alone takes just 280 ms.